# Router handle the back button of the operating system and the AppBar with modal

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show a dialog to handle the output of certain screens of my application. That is, I need to handle both the back button of the operating system and the AppBar.

For example, if we have a screen to create a new product and we want to exit this screen either from the back button or the AppBar, the ideal would be to show a dialog to confirm that you want to go back.

This is what I have in mind

```
// AppRouterDelegate

// I can override the propagation of the back
// button system and it does nothing and let the back
// button of the AppBar do everything.
@override
Future<bool> popRoute() {
  final NavigatorState? navigator = navigatorKey.currentState;
  if (navigator == null) return SynchronousFuture<bool>(false);
  return navigator.maybePop();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Navigator(
    key: navigatorKey,
    pages: [
      const MaterialPage(
        key: HomePage.routeName,
        child: HomePage(),
      ),
      if (appNotifier.newItem)
        const MaterialPage(
          key: ProductAddPage.routeName,
          child: ProductAddPage(),
        )
    ],
    onPopPage: (route, result) {
      if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
      
      if (appNotifier.newItem) {
        appNotifier.setNewItem(false);
      }
      
      return true
    },
  )
}

// ProductAddPage
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Add product"),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
        onPressed: () {
          // Please confirm go to back show dialog and execute
          Navigator.of(context).pop(); // This will trigger AppRouterDelegate._onPopPage()

        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I would have liked to handle it in the _onPopPage but it is a pure function. Remember that I must handle the output of both the operating system button and the application, things should lead to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

use **WillPopScope**

```
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          _moveToScreen2(context, );
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: () {
                  _moveToScreen2(context);
                }),
            title: Text("Screen 1"),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```